# Contain text within

Tags: css

CSS question: I'm wanting a container with 3 inline images with a border around them (not each image). Under the image row and inside the container border I want a sentence or two of text. Without the text the container border is about the same width and height as the image row using display:inline-block, once I add the text the container width is 100%. I want the text to wrap under the image row and not expand beyond the left/right sides of the image row. I would like to know how this can be done and if it can be done using float:left and/or display:inline, display:inline-block. If it can be done both ways what are the pros and cons.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="image1">
    <img src="image2">
    <img src="image3">
    some text
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will create a div, with inner blocks for images and a block for text.  They should both stay 500px.  If the images are > 500px they will be clipped.  The text won't cause it to overflow unless its a very long uninterrupted string.

If this doesn't help, use jsFiddle to put up an example.

CSS

```
.container { 
        width: 500px; 
        overflow: hidden; 
        background:red; 
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="image1">
    <img src="image2">
    <img src="image3">
  </div>
  <div class="caption">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can it also be done without specifying the width of the container element?

Comment: Yes, that was just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Using the example you provided, if I delete the static width the width of the containing element (image row) increases to the width of the text. The text now extends past the left and right sides of the images row. I would like to restrict the text inside the same width as the image row.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of what I'm wanting but with the text below the images. I would also like it to be HTML 5 compatible.

```
<div class="container">
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="image1.jpg" height="200"></td>
<td><img src="image2.jpg" height=200"></td>
</tr>
<caption>a paragraph of text here...</caption>
</table>
</div>

.container {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid;
}

table {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```